# multiprocess open a same file cause file operation failed

Tags: c++, vim, file-io, operating-system, system-calls

During process running , I use `vim aa.txt` and exec `:wq` ,then this process can't print any longer. Why ?

When I check process status by `lsof -p pid`,It show `/home/ben/bypy/sederror/aa.txt~ (deleted)` . By the way , testing in centos.

```
//test.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file("./aa.txt");
    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int iNum = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        file << iNum <<endl;
        iNum++;
        sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `vim` has changed the file `aa.txt` so that the program is writing to a now deleted file.  I'm not confident about this, but it might be what you're seeing, and it might be consistent with the output you see from `lsof`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open a file on Linux, it's identified by device and inode, which isn't reused as long as anything has a reference to it. If you delete the file and create a new one with the same name, any processes that already had it open will still be referring to the old now-deleted one, not the new one. And when you edit files with vi, it doesn't overwrite them in place; it does delete the old one and make a new one.

Comment: See also [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Comment: Note that vim does not always delete the old file and create a new one with the same name, but that is the default behavior if the file has only one link.